# Python implicit nested for loop

Tags: python

I want to iterate over each line read from a file, split them, and then convert each splitted element into floats to create a 2d list of floats.

I have the following code so far:

```
f = open('coordinates.dat')
contents = map(str.strip, f.readlines())
f.close()
```

For each element (line) in `contents`, I want to do `line.split()`, and then for each element in `line.split()`, convert them to floats. Is it possible to do this with implicit loops? The output would look something like this:

```
[[float1, float2, float3], [float4, float5, float6], ... , [floatX, floatY, floatZ]]
```

(There are three numbers on each line of the file)

I tried the following:

```
a = [ line for line in contents for float(i) in line.split()]
```

which gives a sytax error: `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

Comment: FYI, what you call *"implicit loop"* is known as *"list comprehension"* (I'm not trying to be fussy, just giving you the keywords you can look up on a search engine when needed).

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Alright, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rearranging your attempt yields the correct code:

```
a = [[float(i) for i in line.split()] for line in contents]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
a = [[float(i) for i in line.split()] for line in contents]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use map:

```
with open("coordinates.dat") as f:
    out = [list(map(float, sub)) for sub in map(str.split, f)]
```

Or:

```
with open("coordinates.dat") as f:
    out = [list(map(float, sub.split())) for sub in f]
    print(out)
```

Or considering you have numerical data numpy would be useful:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.loadtxt("coordinates.dat")
```

You also don't need to call readlines or `str.strip` to cast to float.